# Why is the signal always entered into minus port in inverting op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

I think output voltage value is same either if I connect input signal into + port or if I connect input signal into - port. The reason why I am thinking like this is come from

$$
V_{out} = -\frac{R_f}{R_{in}} V_-.
$$

I understand the right figure's output is surely -10V because
$$
V_{out} = -\frac{R_f}{R_{in}} V_{in} = -\frac{10000}{1000}{1V} = -10V
$$

However, the left figure's is..... I don't know.

Why does all textbook or other documents use the right circuit instead of left one?

[image]

Comment: The basic idea of your question, that it doesn't matter which terminal you connect the feedback network to, that idea is wrong. Try sweeping V1 and V2 from 0 to 1V and observe the output response.

Comment: *"Why is the signal always entered into minus port in inverting op-amp?"* Actually that is not true. It depends on the function which you want to perform on the signal and the complete circuit.

Comment: The circuit on the left is metastable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with a statement: **The output of an op-amp is

$$ V_{OUT} = A(V_{IN+} - V_{IN-}) $$

Where \$A\$ is the open loop gain, \$V_{IN+}\$ is the non-inverting input voltage and \$V_{IN-}\$ is the inverting input voltage. This is the way opamps are designed and A (the open loop gain) is a large number, typically in the order of 10\$^5\$.

From this we can see that if the '+' is 1mV higher than the '-' input the output will head towards 100 V but get clamped at the positive supply rail. Similarly if the '-' input is 1 mV higher than the '+' input the output will head for -100 V but get clamped by the negative supply rail.

[image]

*Figure 1. Inverting configuration.*

If we apply 1 V at (A) to the inverting configuration the '-' input (point C) will start to rise. We can calculate from our formula that this will drive the output (B) negative. If the output overshoots point C will go negative and the output (B) will go positive. The system will settle down when (C) is very close to the non-inverting input, 0 V.

At this stage we have a voltage divider created by R3 and R4. (A) is at 1 V, (C) is at 0 V so (B) must be at -10 V. We have an amplifier with a gain of -10. i.e., It's inverting.

[image]

*Figure 2. Inputs swapped.*

In the case of Figure 2 we apply 1 V at (A). This starts to pull the voltage at (B) positive. We can see from the gain equation that the output will rise too. The feedback resistor R2 gives positive feedback which pulls the '+' input higher still. If the op-amp is powered from ±12 V then the output will probably rise to about 10 V. With R2 and R1 providing an 11:1 divider the voltage on the '+' input will be 1/11th of the way between 1 and 10 V (about 1.8 V). \$ V_B = (V_C - V_A) \frac {R1}{R1 + R2} + V_1 \$.

If we start to decrease the voltage at (A) nothing happens the output for some time. When (A) is 0 V (B) will be \$ \frac {10}{11} \$ keeping the output at +10 V.

It's only when \$V_A\$ gets to -1 V that the output will start to switch negative.

This arrangement is known as a Schmitt trigger and is very useful for giving a clean switching signal for a noisy input, for example.

Comment: Thank you for a kind answer with good pictures, which made it more understandable.

Answer (score 8):

Your assumption "output voltage value is same either if I connect input signal into + port or if I connect input signal into - port." is wrong.

Your left circuit does not work as a linear amplifier.
Iuses positive Feedback. Depending on the input voltage it saturates close to one of the supply voltages (not shown in your diagramms; probably +10V and -10V; in your case it saturates to -10V).

So the left circuit is not a circuit that makes sense to compare to the right one.
It could be useful, though, as a Schmitt-Trigger (i.e. comparator with hysteresis).

If you compare two (amplifier) circuits, it is not enough to compare input and output voltages of just *one instance* (in your case \$V_{in}\$=1V, \$V_{out}\$=-10V) but of the whole operating range.
If you compared the behaviour of the circuits at other voltages (e.g. \$V_{in}\$=0.5V), you'd have found that they are not equivalent.

Comment: When I asked this question, I did not understand, but finally I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The assumption that the inverting (-) and non-inverting (+) terminals are at approximately the same voltage, is only valid when the op-amp is configured for negative feedback and its output is not saturated.

Negative feedback causes the output to converge such that the inverting terminal and non-inverting terminals are at very close to the same voltage. The larger the open-loop gain, the smaller the voltage difference.

Positive feedback causes the output to diverge away from that balance point, towards either the positive supply limit or the negative supply limit. This is desirable behavior for hysteresis (Schmitt trigger), or memory latch, but not desirable behavior for an amplifier.

It is possible to configure a non-inverting amplifier, that has the input signal applied at the non-inverting (+) input, similar to the circuit you have on the left. But the key difference, is that the feedback (R2) must still connect to the inverting (-) input.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Actually I did not know the inside of op-amp at that time. :)

Answer (score 2):

You've discovered the weakness present in most simulators.

You can wire up an op-amp with positive feedback and find that it appears to be stable producing -10V when the input is +1V and the gain is supposedly |10|.

Yes, reality will also do this but only for about a femto second! Then the output will get disturbed by a tiny bit of noise and it will go crashing into the rails as fast as it can. It goes crashing into the rails because the feedback is positive.

Comment: Andy aka, to be fair, I think we must not blame the simulator. In most cases (and also in the present case) it is the user which is required to know what he is doing. Performing a DC or AC analysis, the simulator "thinks" that the applied DC supply voltages do exist since infinite times. Even a calculation "by hand" leads to a stable amplifier (forgetting that pos. feedback gives instability). This case symbolizes a system of one ball riding upon another one. Under IDEAL conditions, such a system also is stable. Only a TRAN analyses (for a real opamp model) can reveal the instability.

Comment: No blame here..

Comment: I was only referring to the "weakness present in in most simualtors". (smiley). However, not too important ...